# Calculating Euclidean distance between 2 tensors element wise using tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, euclidean-distance

I am available with 2 tensors of shape 64 x 64 x 320 each. How can the euclidean distance between the elements of these tensors be calculated?

Comment: Can you give an example? For, say, 2 x 2 x 4?

Comment: I am simply asking how to calculate Euclidean distance between 2 tensors element-wise. Is an example necessary?

Comment: Do you need it per channel, per batch, for the whole thing? What is the output shape? Before, you wrote the output shape is 64x64x320, so did you mean to calculate the absolute difference?

Comment: per cell wise. Suppose 2 tensors A & B with dimensions 64x64x320.Than euclidean distance between each cell of these tensors. Hence the output shape remains 64x64x320. I thought you got confused by that hence editted

Comment: euclidean(A[0][0][0],B[0][0][0]), euclidean(A[0][1][0],B[0][1][0]),.............euclidean(A[0][0][1],B[0][0][1])..........euclidean(A[64][64][320],B[64][64][320])

Comment: So what you want is actually the absolute difference. That is "euclidean distance" of dimension 1. Did you try `tf.abs(tensor1 - tensor2)`?

Comment: Ohhh!! got it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Euclidian distance in 1 dimension is just absolute difference, so that will be:

```
tf.math.abs(A-B)
```